# Bimodal distribution in C or Python

Tags: python, c, random

What's the easiest way to generate random values according to a bimodal distribution in C or Python?

I could implement something like the Ziggurat algorithm or a Box-Muller transform, but if there's a ready-to-use library, or a simpler algorithm I don't know about, that'd be better.

Comment: Box-Muller won't work -- it's not bimodal. It's two independent values with the same mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aren't you just picking values either of two modal distributions?

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.triangular

Sounds like you just toggle back and forth between two sets of parameters for your call to triangular.

```
def bimodal( low1, high1, mode1, low2, high2, mode2 ):
    toss = random.choice( (1, 2) )
    if toss == 1:
        return random.triangular( low1, high1, mode1 ) 
    else:
        return random.triangular( low2, high2, mode2 )
```

This may do everything you need.

Comment: Would that yield a true bimodal distribution? I don't think that'd work, that's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Worried about the overlapping region?  Keep the two modes far enough apart -- and the slopes steep enough to reduce overlap.  Box-Mueller will have a worse  problem -- it's not bimodal.  It's two independent values with the same mean and standard deviation.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't decide on the distribution (it's from a paper).

Answer (score 2):

There's always the old-fashioned straight-forward [accept-reject algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).  If it was good enough for Johnny von Neumann it should be good enough for you ;-).